# Install wkhtmltopdf on App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, wkhtmltopdf

I have developed a web application in PHP that depends also on wkthmltopdf in order to generate some pdf files.

I would like to deploy it on google (or Amazon), and I was wondering which service it would be more appropriate. I expect a very low workload (20 users/day). Which service would be less costly?

If I use Google App engine standard would it be possible to install wkthmltopdf? If yes how should I proceed?

Many thanks

Comment: I wouldn't imagine so - but take a look at lambda on AWS, I've used it to generate PDF's from wkhtmltopdf and it's not costed a penny - that was hundreds of PDFs per day too :)